# Using java String functions in xslt

Tags: java, string, xslt

I am trying to use the java string function with XSLT 1.0. Specifically the the java String replace function.

But it fails with the null pointer exception. Here's what I tried:

```
1)--Declare namespace and call the java String class 
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:jString="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.lang.String"> 

 2)--Created a template to search for tag inputs that have an ampersand: 
 <xsl:template name="string-replace-all"> 
    <xsl:param name="text" /> 
    <xsl:choose> 
       <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&')"> 
          <xsl:variable name="str1" select="jString:new($text)"/> 
             <xsl:value-of select="jString:replace($str1,'&','&amp;')" /> 
       <xsl:otherwise> 
          <xsl:value-of select="$text" /> 
      </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
 </xsl:template> 

 3)--Call the template in the specific tags 
 <Nm> 
    <xsl:variable name="suppNm"> 
       <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all"> 
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Payee/Name" /> 
       </xsl:call-template> 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$suppNm" /> 
 </Nm>
```

However I keep getting a null pointer exception: 
 Caused by: oracle.xdo.parser.v2.XPathException: Extension function error: Error invoking 'replace':'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Can anyone guide me as to how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `&` by itself is not legal XML.  I’m surprised your XSLT is loaded at all.

Comment: Calling from XSLT to Java depends entirely on which XSLT processor you are using. I suspect from the error message that it's the Oracle processor, but you need to tell us. Why not switch to XSLT 2.0/3.0 where XPath offers regex-based string replacement natively?

Answer (score 1):

Analysing your XSL code:

1. In template `string-replace-all` there is lack of closed tag `when`, so add `</xsl:when>`.
2. Input XML was not represented, so no one knows what the value inside **Payee/Name**. Looking at this part `contains($text, '&')` I suppose `Name` block has value something like `sample1 & sample2`. In case of `&` which is not followed by # (e.g. `&#160;`), the XML parser is implicitly looking for one of the five predefined entity names `lt`, `gt`, `amp`, `quot` and `apos`, or any manually defined entity name. So in input XML the `&` must be escaped as `&amp;`.
3. In case when you use `jString:replace(string, target, replacement)` **NullPointerException** exists if target or replacement is null ([Java.lang.String.replace() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_replace_sequence.htm)), so possibly problem is that target was not picked up cause of `&`. 
   Also for replacing you can use `jString:replaceAll(string, regex, replacement)`.
4. Finally example **Using java String functions in xslt**:

For XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Payee>
    <Name>sample1 &amp; sample2</Name>   
</Payee>
```

Using similar XSL (e.g. replacing `&amp;` with `&quot;`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:jString="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.lang.String" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="jString" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all"> 
       <xsl:param name="text" /> 
       <xsl:choose> 
          <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&amp;')"> 
             <xsl:variable name="str1" select="jString:new($text)"/>                 
             <xsl:value-of select="jString:replaceAll($str1, '&amp;','&quot;')" />
          </xsl:when> 
          <xsl:otherwise> 
             <xsl:value-of select="$text" /> 
         </xsl:otherwise> 
       </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Nm> 
           <xsl:variable name="suppNm"> 
              <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all"> 
                  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/Payee/Name"/> 
              </xsl:call-template> 
           </xsl:variable> 
           <xsl:value-of select="$suppNm" /> 
        </Nm> 
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Nm>sample1 " sample2</Nm>
```

5. Mainly important input XML:

   - If you have it simply text with `&` as below:

   > ```
   > <Payee>
   >     <Name>Jüërgëns GmbH & S's</Name>
   > </Payee>
   > ```

Then you should have error: `The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.`

- If you have `&` in `<![CDATA[]]>` as below:

> ```
> <Payee>
>     <Name><![CDATA[Jüërgëns GmbH & S's]]></Name>
> </Payee>
> ```

Then using XSL as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Nm>
           <xsl:value-of select="/Payee/Name" />
        </Nm> 
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output will be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Nm>Jüërgëns GmbH &amp; S's</Nm>
```

Hope all attentions above will help with your case.

Comment: Hi Thanks very much for your patience in answering my question. I need to escape ampersand with &amp;. But no matter what I try the output comes through as &. Ive tried  1) jString:replaceAll($str1,'&amp;','&amp;amp;') and jString:replaceAll($str1,,'&amp;','&#38;'). Can anyone help me please? This is the alst bit of puzzle I need to figure out. We are using XSLT 1.0

Comment: @springblossom can you add your input XML to question?

Comment: Hi The input XML is a supplier name, Jüërgëns GmbH & S's
I need to replace & with &amp; and ' with &apos;. The replacement of ' with &apos; is working but I havent succeded in replacing & with &amp;. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @springblossom Mainly important how this data parse in input XML, see p.5 I have added to my answer.

Comment: Hi, I cant use CDATA as I need to transform two special characters, & and ' at the same time into &amp; and &apos;. I need to show & as &amp; using Java replace All function. Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution through trial and error. So which the replace for &apos; works well , the same for &amp; does not work. So I used the java String contact function to achieve this:

Here's the final template:

```
 <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&amp;') or contains($text, '&amp;') ">
               <xsl:variable name="str1" select="jString:new(translate($text,'áàâäéèêëíìîïóòôöúùûüç','aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuc'))"/> 
                <xsl:value-of select="(jString:replaceAll(jString:replaceAll($str1,'&amp;',jString:concat('&amp;','amp;')),'&amp;apos;','&amp;amp;apos;'))" />

               </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
           </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>

     </xsl:template>
```